# Apache2.4 Require directive config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, require, apache2.4

I'm trying to set up my Webserver (Raspbian with Owncloud).
I want to use `.htaccess` (or `\<Require>` derective), so that requests from the web should enter user/password but requests from my local network should be allowed to have access.

My apache2.conf <Directory>-Block looks like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For :80 requests the virtual host file redirects to TLS/SSL

```
Redirect permanent "/" "https://myurl"
```

But also has a <Directory>-Block:

```
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Protected"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

For :443 requests the virtual host file with the <Directory>-Block looks like this:

```
        <Directory /var/www/html/protected>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Protected"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
        </Directory>

        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "mag-age=15552000;includeSubDomains"
```

I don't even think that this is trigged somehow because I got no "protected" folder. But idk..

So now I've tried several solutions with my .htaccess file, but either no one can visit my website or everyone can (completely forbidden or full access). I've tried this for testing purposes with two clients in my local network, blocking one, allowing the other (e.g. block 192.168.178.20, allow the rest or vise versa) with several configurations, but its still not working.

.htaccess looks like this atm:

```
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
AuthName "Please Enter Password"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Require ip 192.168.178.22
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

solved this on my own.

ipv6 was the problem. My smartphone automatically switched between ipv4 and ipv6 somehow.
so i now allowed local ipv6 adresses to communicate aswell :)

```
Require ip 1234:123:1234:1234::/64
```